# How to self-sign Windows 7 x64 drivers?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, google, certificate

I have a problem and I haven't been able to get a good answer for this. I want to install drivers on many computers at the same time remotely. The command works but it fails du to timeout.

When I do the command on the computer directly, there is a popup that said if I want to add the driver owners (in this case google) to the trusted publisher. This is what's causing the timeout. I wanted to try to get rid of it but it seems impossible. I had the idea to self-sign the driver certificate but it seems to be impossible for the x64 version of Windows but allowed in 32 bits for some reason.

Anyone have an idea how to proceed? I only want to install that damn drivers remotely and silently.

Comment: Regardless of self-signed or by google you will need to install the certificate as it's used to validate the signature. The `certmgr` utility can be used to install a certificate. See:http://www.deploymentresearch.com/Research/tabid/62/EntryId/63/Sign-your-unsigned-drivers-Damn-It.aspx for an overview.

Comment: Too vague for a "real answer," but you should be able to extract the Google cert, add it to the trusted publisher via a script, and then install your software.  This might point you in the right direction.  http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/24713-silent-install-of-software-that-has-an-unsigned-driver

Answer (score 1):

Brian answer did the trick. For a weird reason... I can't select your answer as an the good answer.

You solved my problem! Sorry it took so long to acknowledge it!

Your link was exactly what I needed!

Comment: You can't mark a comment as accepted. You should remove this [non] answer and post it as a comment asking Brian to make his a real answer.